# Get attribute value from a tag Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm using Linq to get some xml values, but this time I want to get the content of "href" attribute from  tag, which is like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="Value I want to retrieve"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="Another Value want to retrieve"/>
```

any clues how to do that?

I am able to get values of tags

```
<title>1st title</title>
<title>2nd title</title>
```

this way:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> item = document.Descendants(xmlns + "title");
// to print use: item.ElementAt<XElement>(0).Value;
```

But I failed to retrieve a value from the `href` attribute, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `xElem.Attribute("href").Value`

Comment: @Special K. looks like its `html`...if it is.`linq2xml` is not the right choice to parse `html`

Comment: Could be xhtml, in which case it would also be xml.

Comment: It's xml, as stated on the first post I have successfully got some Value of some tags, but I can't get the value of an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
IEnumerable<string> links = document.Descendants("link")
    .Select(element => element.Attribute("href").Value);
```

... or just:

```
var links = document.Descendants("link")
    .Attributes("href")
    .Select(element => element.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use either of those 2 options in a foreach loop? Sorry for such a newb. :)

Comment: @SpecialK. What would you want to iterate over - elements, attributes or both?

Comment: attributes, I only need the attribute values, it will contain some urls.

Comment: Erm... how about simply `foreach (string link in links)` then?

Comment: I have accepted your answer, although can you take a look at this: http://pastebin.com/Uw9c38LY maybe you can include the links in my foreach loop, see "LineFive", that's the place I need them. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @SpecialK. Sorry, don't quite get it: how would you like to assign these links (a Collection) to a single property? Do you need to transform them in some way?

Comment: I need them as a "collection" I think, so each time when the foreach loop runs I need to get the next link, something like int i = 0; foreach(asd as asdf) { asdf(i); /* get the i number line */ i++; }, again thank you so much for your time.